Chrome issue on MACBook, showing invalid string in suggestions and docs
Im not sure if this is the correct portal for my question or not, but I am unable to find anything with the issue I'm facing and that is why trying here in Stackoverflow.
Issues are with my Chrome browser,

when I'm trying to search for something and typing into the search field the suggestions are converted to some invalid strings see this 
The same is happening to Google Docs, like when I'm typing something in Excel and make it bold it's converted in a similar way, like 
Seems like some issue with fonts, as when I'm using WhatsApp in chrome and someone sends me a message in URDU (my local language) it's even not displayed in the browser only space is displayed where on my mobile I can see the message perfectly fine.

Please suggest if anything I need to do for this issue to fix it, I tried asking the same in google community as well but no luck
